# How do I perform asynchronous database queries in a for loop?

Tags: mongodb, express, for-loop, asynchronous, mongoose

In my User schema, I have a property called favorites which stores an array of object Ids from another database that stores quotes. I want to perform a for loop in the favorites property that loops through each id, finds the quote based on that id from the other database, stores the entire quote to a new array, then once all of the quote objects have been added to the array, display a variable containing that array to an ejs view. Here is the code I have tried:

```
router.get('/profile', authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res, next) => {
    // console.log("After AuthenticationMiddleware of /profile load: The user username is: ", req.user.id)

    let quoteIdFavorites = req.user.favorites
    console.log("Started off by storing the ids of your favorite quotes to a variable: ", quoteIdFavorites)

    let listOfQuotes = []
    let getUserFavorites = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < quoteIdFavorites.length; i++) {
            Quote.findById({ _id: quoteIdFavorites[i] }, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Database Error: ", err.message)
                } else {
                    listOfQuotes.push(result)
                    console.log("Quote added. Iteration " + [i] + ": ", result)
                }
            })
        }
        console.log("Post for loop, here are your listOfQuotes: ", listOfQuotes)
        resolve()
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("Promised resolved, now page should begin loading.")
        console.log("And finally, here is what the listOfQuotes variable has in it: ", listOfQuotes)
        res.render('profile', { user: req.user.username, favorites: listOfQuotes })
    })
})
```

Since a for loop is not a promise, I have tried to convert it into one, then once the entire loop finishes, I resolve the promise, then in the .then() method, render the /profile page with the listOfQuotes variable containing the desired results. However, the code in the .then() method still runs first, before all the results have been stored to the array. Here is the order of the output in the console:

```
// Step 1:
Started off by storing the ids of your favorite quotes to a variable:  ["59f8defdfc62ebaba24ad627","59f8ddf69ad7b6ab6be6629e"]

// Step 2:
Post for loop, here are your listOfQuotes:  []

// Step 3:
Promised resolved, now page should begin loading.

// Step 4: empty?
And finally, here is what the listOfQuotes variable has in it:  []

// Step 5: load page
GET /profile 200 48.937 ms - 1905

// Step 6: why are the quotes just now being added to the array? the page has already loaded!
Quote added. Iteration 0:  { _id: 59f8defdfc62ebaba24ad627,
  updatedAt: 2017-10-31T20:37:17.279Z,
  createdAt: 2017-10-31T20:37:17.279Z,
  quote: 'how bout now',
  author: 'well',
  __v: 0 }
Quote added. Iteration 1:  { _id: 59f8ddf69ad7b6ab6be6629e,
  updatedAt: 2017-10-31T20:32:54.290Z,
  createdAt: 2017-10-31T20:32:54.290Z,
  quote: 'still work please',
  author: 'thanks',
  __v: 0 }

// Step 7: load in styles
GET /stylesheets/profile.css 200 37.570 ms - 5014
GET /javascripts/main.js 200 11.248 ms - 5800
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Quote.find({ _id: {$in: quoteIdFavorites} })` and iterate the cursor. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find

Comment: This works. Thanks!